# What does 홀홀 웃으며 mean in English?

Tags: translation, meaning

나 지금 친구에게 문자하고있어. "홀홀 웃으며" I don't understand what it means. If anyone can translate for me, I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: I'm korean but 홀홀 웃으며....
so strange to feeling 호호 웃으며
this is a right

Comment: Where is this from? Please add more context.

Answer (score 1):

훌훌 웃다 is not a common phrase (I've never heard it before).

훌훌 is a common onomatopoeic adverb describing something happening or done in a very light and breezy manner.  It can be used about natural phenomena or certain actions ("씨를 훌훌 뿌렸다" = Sprinkled the seeds all around). One of the most common usage nowadays is in phrases like 훌훌 털다 or 훌훌 털어 버리다 (털다 = to dust off; to free oneself of something), which means to forget about something once and for all rather than obsessing with it (often used about ending a relationship or other thorny matters).

훌훌 웃다 probably means laughing lightheartedly while touching on many different subjects in quick succession.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a common phrase.
but if I had got one like that, I would have just thought of it as "ㅎㅎ"
It's something like "LOL" in English.

It just means that your friend was having fun sending texts.